# A B+tree simple implementation in C

Tags: c, database, tree, implementation, b-tree

I'm working on a fun project where I need a simple key/value store that uses B+Trees. I studied them some years ago, and to be honest, I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I'm looking for a simple implementation in C of b+tree that I can just include in my project.

I know of sqlite's, dbm's and tokyocabinet's ones but they're a little too "complicated" for my needs. Is there any (even pedagogical) work on this you can refer me to? Do you have some code to share?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are many links where you can read and implement for yourself(which is the best way since it helps you learn).
But if you dont have time you can see one forum here.

You can customize it to your needs

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=453150

Comment: Thanks Chaithra! Together with the link @marcog submitted, I think I can write me something.

Answer (score 4):

There's one listed in the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree#Implementations) article:

- [Interactive B+ Tree Implementation in C](http://www.amittai.com/prose/bplustree.html)

Perhaps you can edit out the "interactive" parts?

Comment: Thank, Marco! I stumbled on this I think and didn't gave too much importance. Now, I know I should have!